# Any way to get a list of functions defined in a module?

Tags: julia

Is there any introspective magic that would give me a list of functions defined in a module?

```
module Foo
  function foo()
    "foo"
  end
  function bar()
    "bar"
  end
end
```

Some mythical function like:

```
functions_in(Foo)
```

Which would return: [foo,bar]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I see the list of methods in a Julia Package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661590/how-can-i-see-the-list-of-methods-in-a-julia-package)

Comment: @IainDunning: I tried names(Foo) but it only returns :Foo

Comment: For the buildin functions I'm trying to create a listing with examples: http://www.jlhub.com/julia/manual/en/function-reference You may find it useful. If there's interest I'll expand it to cover popular modules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is that both `names` and `whos`  list *exported* names from a module. If you wanted to see them then you would need to do something like this:

```
module Foo

export foo, bar

function foo()
    "foo"
end
function bar()
    "bar"
end
end  # module
```

At this point both `names` and `whos`  would list everything.

If you happen to be working at the REPL and for whatever reason did not want to export any names, you could inspect the contents of a module interactively by typing `Foo.[TAB]`. See an example from this session:

```
julia> module Foo
         function foo()
           "foo"
         end
         function bar()
           "bar"
         end
       end

julia> using Foo

julia> whos(Foo)
Foo                           Module

julia> names(Foo)
1-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :Foo

julia> Foo.
bar  eval  foo
```

Somehow the tab completion is looking up un-exported names, so there *must* be a way to get Julia to tell them to you. I just don't know what that function is.

#### EDIT

---

I did a little digging. The un-exported function `Base.REPLCompletions.completions` seems to work, as demonstrated in a continuation of the REPL session we were previously using:

```
julia> function functions_in(m::Module)
           s = string(m)
           out = Base.REPLCompletions.completions(s * ".", length(s)+1)

           # every module has a function named `eval` that is not defined by
           # the user. Let's filter that out
           return filter(x-> x != "eval", out[1])
       end
functions_in (generic function with 1 method)

julia> whos(Foo)
Foo                           Module

julia> names(Foo)
1-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :Foo

julia> functions_in(Foo)
2-element Array{UTF8String,1}:
 "bar"
 "foo"
```

Comment: You need to use `names(M, true)` to get unexported symbols.

Comment: @Isaiah, great comment. I didn't know about that option.

Comment: For Julia 1.2 @IsaiahNorton's useful comment should read `names(M, all = true)`

Comment: Note that `names(M, all=true)` returns a handful junk as well, including (but not limited to?) `Symbol("#eval")`, `Symbol("#include")`, and the module itself.