# How to list all of Julia's internal variables?

Tags: julia, read-eval-print-loop

Julia has a number of internal variables such as WORD_SIZE (indicates whether target system is 32- or 64-bit) and CPU_CORES (number of cpu cores presently available).

In the Julia REPL, is there some way to list all of these internal variables?

AFAIK, `whos` and `names(Main)` does not show them...

EDIT: From this [previous question on listing exported function names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28731902/any-way-to-get-a-list-of-functions-defined-in-a-module), I see that `names(Base)` does show these internal variables, along with every other exported item in the `Base` module.

Comment: those variables are in a submodule of the Base, `whos(Base.Sys) ` shows them.

Comment: Thanks! Put that as an answer, and I will mark that down as correct, @GnimucK.

Comment: That does not list all the variables for me, just a few of them. Not, say, JULIA_HOME, STDIN, ENV, etc.

Comment: @DNF hm, yes, I see that now... so that means my question is still unanswered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @DNF pointed in the comment above, `whos(Base.Sys)` won't print all the **internal(constant)** variables in `Base`. but we can search those variables directly from `whos(Base)` via:

```
julia> whos(Base, r"^\s*[A-Z_]+$")
                          ARGS      0 bytes  0-element Array{UTF8String,1}
                          BLAS    214 KB     Module
                     CPU_CORES      8 bytes  Int64
                        C_NULL      8 bytes  Ptr{Void}
                    ENDIAN_BOM      4 bytes  UInt32
                           ENV      0 bytes  Base.EnvHash with 29 entries
                          FFTW    149 KB     Module
                          HTML    168 bytes  DataType
                             I      8 bytes  UniformScaling{Int64}
                            IO     92 bytes  DataType
                    JULIA_HOME     66 bytes  ASCIIString
                        LAPACK    933 KB     Module
                     LOAD_PATH    190 bytes  2-element Array{ByteString,1}
                          MIME    148 bytes  DataType
                       OS_NAME      0 bytes  Symbol
                        STDERR    217 bytes  Base.TTY
                         STDIN     64 KB     Base.TTY
                        STDOUT    217 bytes  Base.TTY
                       VERSION     40 bytes  VersionNumber
                     WORD_SIZE      8 bytes  Int64
```

this lies in the fact that Julia's constants are UPPERCASE. you may find that some **Module**s are also in the list, but it's easy to identify. indeed, one can use a more complex regex to expel them.

note that, those variables which are not exported into `Base` will not shown out. e.g.

```
whos(Base.Libdl)
```

Comment: Ah, I was also trying to use a regexp, but with an anonymous function and `find`. Your solution is much better.